# edit my profile page not updating the user profile

Tags: php

I have an update page for the user

so the fetch query is working fine but when I click submit it gives me profile has been updated then I refresh the page I see nothing updated.

the page doesn't show any kind of error
, I'm so confused about this ...

here's my code :

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_profile'])) {

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$user_avatar = $_FILES ['user_avatar']['name'];
$user_avatar_temp = $_FILES['user_avatar']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($user_avatar_temp, "./user_avatar/$user_avatar");

if(empty($user_avatar)){


       $query = "SELECT user_avatar FROM users WHERE username = '{$the_user_id}' ";

       $select_image = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
       if(!$select_image){

         die('rip'.mysqli_error($connection));
       }
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_image)){

           $user_avatar = $row['user_avatar'];
       }

             }

             $param_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
             $error = NULL;
             if (empty($password)) {
                 $error = 'You forgot to choose a password!';
             }
             if (!$error) {

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "firstname = '{$firstname}', ";
    $query .= "lastname = '{$lastname}', ";
    $query .= "username = '{$username}', ";
    $query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
    $query .= "user_avatar = '{$user_avatar}', ";
    $query .= "password = '{$param_password}', ";
    $query .= "WHERE username = '{$the_user_id}' ";
}



    $edit_user_query =mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if(!$edit_user_query){

  die('rip'.mysqli_error($connection));
}


     echo "<div class='alert alert-success fade in'>
  <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
  <strong>Success!</strong> Your profile has been edited
</div>";


}
```

you can take a look at the full code with the form on Pastebin :

[pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/16f4Tuap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not checking to see if the error is empty when running the query;

```
         if (!$error) {

    $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
    $query .= "firstname = '{$firstname}', ";
    $query .= "lastname = '{$lastname}', ";
    $query .= "username = '{$username}', ";
    $query .= "email = '{$email}', ";
    $query .= "user_avatar = '{$user_avatar}', ";
    $query .= "password = '{$param_password}', ";
    $query .= "WHERE username = '{$the_user_id}' ";
}



    $edit_user_query =mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Therefore if there is an error it will run the previous select query.